# Changing the themeColor of CheckBoxListTile globally using material3

Tags: flutter, flutter-theme

In Flutter [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/toggleable-active-color#:%7E:text=ThemeData.toggleableActiveColor%20is%20deprecated%20and%20will%20eventually%20be%20removed.,eventually%20be%20removed%2C%20as%20per%20Flutter%E2%80%99s%20deprecation%20policy.), it's given

> The Material widgets `Switch`, `SwitchListTile`, `Checkbox`, `CheckboxListTile`, `Radio`, `RadioListTile` now use `ColorScheme.secondary` color for their toggleable widget.
> `ThemeData.toggleableActiveColor` is deprecated and will eventually be removed.

But CheckboxListTile is using `ColorScheme.primary` for the `toggleableActiveColor` instead of `ColorScheme.secondary`

My Main Theme:

```
ThemeData(
   material3 : true,
   colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
     seedColor: DesignColor.green,
     primary: DesignColor.green,
     onPrimary: DesignColor.primaryTextColor,
     secondary: DesignColor.yellow,
     onSecondary: DesignColor.white))
```

My CheckboxListTile:

```
CheckboxListTile(
      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
      title: Text(range999),
      value: values[1],
      onChanged: (val) {})
```

Output:

[image]

Note: The documentation works if i remove `usematerial3:true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a `checkboxTheme` property inside `ThemeData`.

You can update something like this.

```
checkboxTheme: CheckboxThemeData(
      fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.purple),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
      ),
      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade100, width: 1.5),
    ),
```

Happy coding:)